# how to use google api keys based on heroku application name

Tags: google-maps, development-environment, heroku

I've created a few different "environments" for my app that is hosted on heroku so I have:
appName-staging.heroku.com
appName-production.heroku.com

I want to use different google api keys for these applications, how do I do this?
i've created a google.yml file that looks like:

development:
  api_key: 'ABCXYZ'

production:
  api_key: 'DEFXYZ'

so I use ABCSZY when developing locally, and DEFXYZ for appName-production.heroku.com
question is, how do i get appName-staging.heroku.com to use a different key?

since every application deployed to Heroku is considered to be in "production", both 
appName-staging.heroku.com and appName-production.heroku.com use the same key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a [heroku config variable](http://docs.heroku.com/config-vars) to each environment, allowing you to identify each one from within the app.

Something along the lines of:

```
$ heroku config:add APP_NAME_ENV=production --app appName-production
$ heroku config:add APP_NAME_ENV=staging --app appName-staging
```

Then you could grab the current environment from within your app using:

```
ENV['APP_NAME_ENV']
```

And if you've got your YAML file as a hash called something like `GOOGLE_KEYS`, the following would return the correct key for a given environment:

```
GOOGLE_KEYS[ENV['APP_NAME_ENV']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer definitely works but doesn't account for the potential security threats which come with checking files which include private keys into source control. Having your google.yml file in source control will allow anyone with access to your repo to see your private API keys.

A more secure solution would be to delete the google.yml file and create different environment variables on your staging and production servers with the same key:

```
$ heroku config:add GOOGLE_API_KEY=<production key> --app appName-production
$ heroku config:add GOOGLE_API_KEY=<development key> --app appName-staging
```

Then, when this is needed you can refer to it in code via

```
ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']
```

This will allow you to share code without sharing your private API keys.

Some more information on using environment variables on Heroku can be found at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars