# Google maps API v3 Key not working on heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, google-maps-api-3

Trying to run an app on Heroku and the Google maps API V3 key keeps throwing errors but runs locally.

My Key

```
  %script{ type: "text/javascript", src: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIz............."}
```

I have also tried without https:

And the error

This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html.

And previously the error was

invalidkeyorunauthorizedurlmaperror:....

I have regenerated the key but not sure of the cause? Is this a heroku specific problem.

Comment: See if this answers your question: [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333688/how-to-use-google-api-keys-based-on-heroku-application-name)